# Why does my effect plot generated with lme4 and effects packages seem wrong?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, logistic-regression, effects

I fitted a generalized linear mixed model to my dataset using the lme4 package in R. The model formula and output are below:

[image]

Because I found a significant interaction between "period" and "Adjunct", I tried to look deeper by extracting their effects and plotting the interaction with the package effects. I tried to obtain the effects using the scripts below:

```
var.adSem <- data.frame(Effect(c("period", "AdjunctSem"), m7))
head(var.adSem)
var.adSem $ period <- droplevels(var.adSem $ period)
levels(var.adSem $ period)
var.adSem $ AdjunctSem <- droplevels(var.adSem $ AdjunctSem)
levels(var.adSem $ AdjunctSem)
```

And these are the effects I extracted:

[image]

And I tried to plot the effects using the scripts below:

```
perc <- function(x) {paste(100 * x, "%")}
Plot1<-(ggplot(var.adSem,aes(x=factor(period, level=c('period_1', 'period_2','period_3')),fit, shape=AdjunctSem))
        + geom_hline(yintercept=.5, linetype="dashed", alpha=.5)  
        + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=fit-se,ymax=fit+se),width=.2,position = position_dodge(0.3))
        #    + annotate("rect", xmin = c(4.5, 6.5), xmax = c(5.5, 9.5),
        #           ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
        #           alpha = 0.2, fill = c("#6ac2ee"))
        + geom_point(size=4, position = position_dodge(0.3))
        + labs(y="Probability of the ba-construction", x="period")
        + theme(#plot.title = element_text(size=20, face="bold", vjust=2),
          plot.title   = element_blank(),
          axis.title.x = element_text(size=14, vjust=-0.5),
          axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5),
          axis.title.y = element_text(size=14, vjust=1.5),
          legend.position = "top")
        + scale_y_continuous(label=function(x){paste(100*x,"%")}, 
                             breaks=seq(0,1,.1),
                             limits=c(0,1)))
```

And the resulting plot looks like this:

[image]

It seems from the effect plot that there are no obvious interactions at all. However, the model output clearly indicates a significant interaction (*p*<0.001). Is it because I made a mistake somewhere in the scripts? Please click this [link](https://osf.io/4pmh3/) if you would like access to the dataset.

Comment: Try changing `scale_y_continuous` to `scale_y_log10`. You'll see there _is_ a large difference.

Comment: I tried to implement this change to my existing scripts and R returned this error message: Error in seq.default(a, b, length.out = n + 1) : 
  'from' must be a finite number
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In self$trans$transform(x) : NaNs produced
2: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis

Comment: *aside:* this is the first time ever I saw the `$` operator being used with surrounding spaces. Works, though :-)

Comment: @nick.yili9393 remove the `breaks` argument or change it to something like `breaks = 10^(seq(-10, 0))`- you can't have a log scale with a break at 0

Comment: I tried twice, once by removing the breaks argument and once by changing the function according to your suggestion. However, R still returns the same error. I think it is because I do not fully understand the motivation here to change to a log scale. Can you please explain in a bit more details? Also, can you please provide more detailed scripts to show how this should be done? Please feel free to use the original data available in the link above.

Comment: The link doesn't contain any data. The linked project has a single file in it, which is just an R script. It seems to try to load data from an Excel file on your local drive, but of course we don't have this file. The rationale for changing to a log scale is that the probabilities are close to zero (and in fact all look like zero because they are so close to it), but are still orders of magnitude apart (visually, 0.001 is indistinguishable from 0.00001, but there is a large difference in terms of their log odds (which is how you have modelled them)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your question to include the output etc. as text, not as images.  The extreme coefficients you have (absolute value > 10) suggest that you have *complete* separation*, which will lead to lots of predictions near 0 or near 1 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a binomial model, which means the significant differences that are reported in your model summary are differences in *log odds*. However, these have been converted to *probabilities* in `var.adSem`.

If you have large log odds, the equivalent probabilities are close to one. Large negative log odds will be close to 0. The relationship is not linear, so that if you view log odds as probabilities, the high log odds will all appear compressed as probabilities close to 1, whereas the low log odds will appear compressed as probabilities close to 0.

We can illustrate this by taking a vector representing log odds and seeing what happens when we convert them to probabilities. First, the log odds:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = seq(-10, 10), log_odds = seq(-10, 10))

ggplot(df, aes(x, log_odds)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image]

Now we convert the log odds to probabilities using `plogis`:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, plogis(log_odds))) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image]

Note that even though there is a constant change in log odds across the range, the change in probabilities becomes difficult to see above log odds of 5 or below log odds of -5, because the probabilities are close to 0 or close to 1.

With your own data, this means if you want to demonstrate the difference between groups, you need to show the results as log odds. You can transform the y axis so that it still shows probabilities, though the probabilities are so close to 0 and 1 that percentages become an unconventional choice:

```r
ggplot(var.adSem, aes(x = period, y = qlogis(fit), shape = AdjunctSem)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = qlogis(0.5), linetype = "dashed", alpha = 0.5)  +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = qlogis(lower), ymax = qlogis(upper)), width = 0.2, 
                position = position_dodge(0.3)) +
  geom_point(size = 4, position = position_dodge(0.3)) +
  labs(x = "period") +
  theme(plot.title      = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x    = element_text(size  = 14, vjust = -0.5),
        axis.text.x     = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        axis.title.y    = element_text(size  = 14, vjust = 1.5),
        legend.position = "top") +
  scale_y_continuous("Probability of the ba-construction",
                     labels = ~scales::percent(plogis(.x)),
                     breaks = qlogis(c(1e-9, 1e-6, 1e-3, 0.5,
                                       1 - 1e-3, 1 - 1e-6, 1 - 1e-9)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data obtained from OCR of table in question**

```r
var.adSem <- structure(list(period = c("period_2", "period_1", "period_3", 
"period_2", "period_1", "period_3", "period_2", "period_1", "period_3"
), AdjunctSem = c("adverbial", "adverbial", "adverbial", "complement", 
"complement", "complement", "withoutAdjunct", "withoutadjunct", 
"withoutadjunct"), fit = c(3.51860434e-05, 2.737536e-07, 0.9999899965756, 
1.97090038e-05, 4.566828e-07, 0.9999909905965, 3.5261392e-05, 
2.81571e-07, 0.9999885020845), se = c(3.46701653e-05, 5.871505e-07, 
2.82682182e-05, 1.96541803e-05, 9.787531e-07, 2.56165218e-05, 
3.48405297e-05, 6.051007e-07, 3.28484263e-05), lower = c(5.100729398e-06, 
4.089689e-09, 0.997462272508378, 2.79139626e-06, 6.844419e-09, 
0.997634501991402, 5.084413615e-06, 4.171972e-09, 0.996901835438947
), upper = c(0.00024267862, 1.832405e-05, 0.99999996067, 0.00013914363, 
3.047052e-05, 0.99999996577, 0.00024450078, 1.900319e-05, 0.99999995746
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9"))
```